# Usage of Force Majeure

Tags: word-usage

Can you use ***Force Majeure*** in understanding as "a situation that forces you to act contrary to your intentions or plan" by which I mean usage of this word not only in law terms.

Let's say: Jack and Tom agreed to go somewhere but unforeseen circumstance happened, for example, one of them broke leg or torrential rain began etc which ruined their plans to do anything. (Force Majeure).

Comment: Nobody outside the legal profession uses _force majeure_.

Comment: force majeur means events you have no control over an event and is seen in **insurance contracts**: Floods, storms etc. are considered force majeure events.

Comment: Ok, but what's word fits best in this understanding?

Comment: What's wrong with "unforeseen circumstances"?

Comment: @gotube I just want to get one-word term

Comment: "Force majeure" isn't one word.

Comment: There are many possibilities from "fate" or "the hand of God" or "bad luck" to "external forces" or "the unexpected". It depends upon  what exactly you want to convey. Do you want something formal and legal, or something folksy, or scary, or minimising or maximising the severity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody outside the legal profession uses *"force majeure"*. –
It means
events you have no control over and is seen in insurance contracts: Floods, storms etc. are considered force majeure events.

A short alternative expression could be "unforeseen circumstances"?

> Jack and Tom were unable to go to where they had agreed, due to unforeseen circumstances.

Note that using generic expression like "force majeure" or "unforeseen circumstances" creates the impression that you are deliberately hiding the details. If possible it may be better to be specific:

> Jack and Tom agreed to go somewhere but were prevented by a rail strike.

Comment: Comments -> CW.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146571/discussion-on-answer-by-james-k-usage-of-force-majeure); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.